# Power set cardinality confusion

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I am reading a book that claims that if $|A|=2$, $|C|=3$ then 
$$
|P(P(A)\times P(C))|=32
$$
How is this computed? I would think the cardinality of the above should be $2^{2^{|A|}*2^{|C|}}=2^{4*8}=2^{32}$. What am I missing? As I am trying to compute these quickly, I would like to avoid enumerating things mechanically.

Comment: This is probably a typo, an extra $P(.)$. In any event, your computation is correct.

Comment: I agree with you, $|P(P(A)\times P(C))|=2^{32}$. Probably the first $P$ is just a typo.

Comment: |A| = 2 so |P(A)| = 2^2 = 4.  |B|=3 so |P(B)| = 2^3 = 8. cross-product.?.... okay.  |XxY| = |X|x|Y| so |P(A)xP(B)| = 4x8 = 32.  So |P(P(A)xP(B))|= 2^{32}.  So... not sure what the typo was but... there is one somewhere... not sure why one would be interested in the set of subsets of the cross products of subsets of A with subsets of B but if someone is the order is 2^32.

Comment: @fleablood: Well you never know what you may come across while doing some maths right?

Comment: It is a nice example of how things can grow really fast.  I find it mildly interesting that |P(AxB)| = 64 while |P(a)xP(b)|= 32.  It's interesting... but not *that* interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ts a typo. The cardinality of |P(A)| = 2^2 = 4, |P(B)| = 2^3 = 8. The cardinality of the Cartesian product of the power sets is 4*8=32. Thus the cardinality of |P(P(A)×P(C))| = 2^32.